# I am facing a weird issue with the "products in category" that reverts back from time to time on Magento 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, category

I am facing a weird issue with the "products in category" that reverts back from time to time on Magento 2.2.4

So if I change the products it suddenly rolls back to the products that were there before. For example The Category is "Coffee" but it was previously sausages. So from time to time those sausages come back. I've removed the sausages maybe more than 5x now.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? I have a team who's also working under but no one said they touched the "products in category" part.